# Replicating output of Stata's psgraph using python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Stata, there is a function called psgraph that is a histogram of the propensity score for treated and untreated groups, with the untreated bars essentially mirrored over the x-axis to make for easy comparison (depicted below). I am trying to make a similar graph in Python using matplotlib, but am not sure how to make the axes align.

[image: Output from Stata's psgraph]

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
random_data=pd.DataFrame(columns=['treated','pscore'])
random_data['treated']=np.random.randint(0,2,size=1000)
random_data['pscore']=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.hist(random_data['pscore'][random_data['treated']==1],bins=50);
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.hist(random_data['pscore'][random_data['treated']==0],bins=50,color='orange');
ax2.invert_yaxis()
```

And here is the output:

[image: output from python]

What I am looking for is a way to make it so that the zero on the y-axis aligns for the two x-axes and have the orange bars going down from there and the blue going up (to mimic the idea Stata graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question! This works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_axes_aligner import align
random_data=pd.DataFrame(columns=['treated','pscore'])
random_data['treated']=np.random.randint(0,2,size=1000)
random_data['pscore']=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.hist(random_data['pscore'][random_data['treated']==1],bins=50);
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.hist(random_data['pscore'][random_data['treated']==0],bins=50,color='orange');
ax2.invert_yaxis()
org1 = 0.0
org2 = 0.0
pos = 0.5
align.yaxes(ax, org1, ax2, org2, pos)
```

[image]